# How prove the function could extend continuously to completion of metric spaces is equivalent to the function maps Cauchy sequence to Cauchy sequence?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

The question comes from my friend. We had a long discussion but only got a complex answer. I wish to get a simply answer.

To be more precise,

> Given two metrix spaces $ X $ and $ Y $, a (continuous) function $f \colon X \to Y$. The following conditions is equivalent.
>
> 1. $ f $ maps Cauchy sequence to Cauchy sequence;
> 2. for the completion $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$, there exists an continuous extension $\hat{f} \colon \hat{X} \to \hat{Y}$, that means, the restriction of $\hat{f}$ on $X$ is equal to $f$, and $\hat{f}$ is continuous.

My main doubts about this issue is it might not maintain Cauchy continuity. Because imaging the sequence on sequence is difficult for me.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending continuous functions to the completion (metric spaces).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2243730/extending-continuous-functions-to-the-completion-metric-spaces)

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: @user264745 My friend proves continuity on $X$ by continuity of the function on each compact subset. He knows on a compact set, the Cauchy continuity could conclude that uniform continuity. And he thought it is trivial that the uniform continuity could have a continuous extension. 
I used the convergence theory. I supposed the intersecion of equivalent Cauchy filters is also a Cauchy filter (called minimal filter). So I define the topological structure with concept of contour. Then noticed that the image of a minimal filter is minimal. Thus the proof is complete.

Comment: @geetha290krm Not exactly. I mainly want to know the continuity after the extended. But thanks a lot, I didn't consider whether this extension is well-defined.

Comment: If you interweave two convergent sequences with the same limit, it also converges to the same limit. That is, if $$c_n = \begin{cases} a_{n/2}& n\text{ even}\\b_{(n+1)/2}&n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$ and $\lim_n a_n = \lim_n b_n = L$, then it is also true that $\lim_n c_n = L$. This is a key fact for this problem.

Comment: @PaulSinclair sorry, i can't understand how this property helps to prove.